# \label with \includepdf links to previous page

Tags: cross-referencing, pdfpages

It seems that using `\includepdf` along with `\label` links to the previous page. I tried to put the `\label` in the `pagecommand=` option,  but this produced identical results.  I had expected that using the `\label` in the `pagecommand=` would link me to the last page.

The MWE below starts the `\includepdf` on the second page. The page number is correct, but clicking on it takes you to the first page.  TeXShop provides a preview of the page that is linked and it shows that the link is to page 1, even though it should be page 2.

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\def\PdfFile{/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/doc/latex/mwe/mwe.pdf}%

\listfiles
\begin{document}
    \tableofcontents
    \clearpage\newpage
    \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{MWE Document}%
    \label{MWE Document}%
    \includepdf[
        frame,
        scale=0.90,
        page=-,
        nup=2x1,
        pagecommand={%
            \section*{MWE Document}%
            %\label{MWE Document}% <-- same result
        },
    ]{\PdfFile}
\end{document}
```

Comment: After posing I found a solution, but is there a way to only have a single `\includepdf`? Or perhaps automate it with a macro that separates these two.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The label has nothing to do at all with the link. It is only relevant if you use a `\ref` somewhere.

The link in the table of contents typically goes to a section heading. Here you want it to go to the `\addcontentsline`. For this you need an anchor which you can set with `\phantomsection`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\def\PdfFile{example-image-a4-numbered}%

\listfiles
\begin{document}
    \tableofcontents
    \clearpage\newpage
    \phantomsection %<---------anchor
    \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{MWE Document}%
    \label{some-label}%
    \includepdf[
        frame,
        scale=0.90,
        pages=-,
        nup=2x1,
        pagecommand={%
            \section*{MWE Document}%
        },
    ]{\PdfFile}
\end{document}
```

pdfpages has some options for automatic anchors, check the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

One way to get this to work, is to split the pages into two separate `\includepdf`:

1. pages that are typset on the first page (and use `\addcontentsline` and `\label`) and the remainder of the page.  Since I am using `nup=2x1`, this is `page=1-2`.
2. remainder of the pages don't use `\addcontentsline` and `\label`. With `nup=2x1`, this is `page=3-`

#### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\def\PdfFile{/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/doc/latex/mwe/mwe.pdf}%

\listfiles
\begin{document}
    \tableofcontents
    \clearpage\newpage
    \includepdf[
        frame,
        scale=0.90,
        page=1-2,
        nup=2x1,
        pagecommand={%
            \section*{MWE Document}%
            \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{MWE Document}%
            \label{MWE Document}%
        },
    ]{\PdfFile}
    \includepdf[
        frame,
        scale=0.90,
        page=3-,
        nup=2x1,
        pagecommand={%
            \section*{MWE Document}%
        },
    ]{\PdfFile}
\end{document}
```